# Retrive image file from folder and display into Image Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have save my Image using Below code In a Folder in my source file..
now I have to retrvive the same saved Image on my Form

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileupload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    string strtemp = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyhhmmss_") + filename;
    fileupload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Image/" + strtemp));
```

So how should i give a Path to my Image Control
I have tried something like this to get a path of file and folder but simply i cant fetch the image from it into my image folder

```
Image2.ImageUrl = (Server.MapPath("Image/" + strtemp));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
Image2.ImageUrl = "~/Image/" + strtemp;
```

`Server.MapPath` is used to get the physical path of a resource of your server. You need it for operations like saving files. However your physical path is not valid on the web. You should use the virtual path to specify the url.

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch Image like this.:-

```
Image2.ImageURL = "~/Image/"+strtemp;
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

`Image2.ImageUrl = "~\\Image\\" + strtemp;`

Use the above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text==""))
{
    string a = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
    string [] q  = a.Split('/');

    string qq  =    q[1];
    Image1.Visible = true;
    Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images1/" + qq;
}
```